# Почему не подключается библиотека treeview:0.1.3?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle

**Введение:**
Доброго времени суток уважаемые программисты! Уже 3 месяца вынашиваю в голове идею написать программу для андроид под названием "PrYFam", что расшифровывается, как ProudYourFamily. Короче приложение, куда человек, сможет добавлять информацию о своей семье, строить древо и т.д.

**Пожалуйста, помогите и дайте дельный совет**
Итак, нужно что то вроде инструкции, как сделать приложение под android(на java), чтобы:

- Был холст(не canvas наверное), по которому пользователь сможет перемещаться, свайпая его 2умя пальцами типа как в галерее.
- Вот кстати, очень важно, что это длжен быть не canvas, а что то другое...
- Узлы дерева- это какие нибудь карточки с возможностью открываться на весь экран.
  Прошу просто помочь советом, последние 2 пункта меня волнуют больше всего, спасибо. Может кто - то скажет вообще без библиотек всё делать, делать самому... Но тогда какие шаги должны быть????

**Библиотеку я нашел:**

Члены семьи должны отображаться, очевидно, в виде дерева. Нужная библиотека(см.видос) - https://yandex.ru/video/preview/10017363285474036205.

Сама библиотека git hub(тут и инструкция, как её подключать): https://github.com/nezne1k4/TreeView?ysclid=lb173erax5906093263

И вот у них всё просто. Читайте дальше...

**И вроде всё классно:**
Вот такой implementation 'de.blox.treeview:treeview:0.1.3' предлагает автор видео. Я знаю, что существует 3 способа добавления библиотек в Android Studio, в 1ом из них достаточно включить эту строку в файл build.gradle App. Что я и делаю...

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'de.blox.treeview:treeview:0.1.3'   // here my implementation

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}
```

**Возникает ошибка при попытке собрать(Sync Now) проект:**

```
Failed to resolve: de.blox.treeview:treeview:0.1.3 <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a> Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/KoreshNoyt/Desktop/KoreshFlesh/AndroidProgramming/MyApplication/app/build.gradle">app</a>
```

Кстати я пробовал аналогичным образом подключать другие библиотеки, например, graphview, там всё работает.

**Вы скажете это "предупреждение", а не ошибка...**

Да! Но она предупреждает о том, что невозможно подключить эту библиотеку. То есть в файл main.xml я, очевидно не смогу довабить заветные строки:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <de.blox.treeview.TreeView      // System can't understand this block :(
     android:id="@+id/treeview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </de.blox.treeview.TreeView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Таким образом, я не могу вызывать никакие команды из этой библиотеки...

**И еще вопрос:**
Допустим мне удалось эту библиотеку как то подключить, а как дальше сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на "ребёнка" дерева открывалось доп.окно, куда можно вписать информацию о человеке, его атрибуты всякие, как накручивать функционал????

Comment: В вашем вопросе содержится сразу несколько вопросов, попробуйте переформулировать ваш вопрос, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме. Это поможет другим участникам дать конкретный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы использовать библиотеку в вашем проекте, она должна находиться в публичном maven-репозитории, например, [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/).

Указанная в вопросе библиотека [не опубликована](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.blox.treeview/treeview) в репозитории Maven Central.

Чтобы использовать [TreeView](https://github.com/nezne1k4/TreeView), возможны следующие варианты:

1. Подключить репозиторий jcenter (**не рекомендуется**, этот репозиторий устарел, не обновляется и может содержать небезопасные библиотеки)
2. Попросить разработчиков библиотеки опубликовать ее в Maven Central
3. Самостоятельно собрать библиотеку из исходного кода и подключить ее в проект как jar или aar зависимость
4. Использовать библиотеку [GraphView](https://github.com/oss-bandb/GraphView) вместо [TreeView](https://github.com/nezne1k4/TreeView)
5. Создать свой maven-репозиторий, подключить его в проект, самостоятельно собрать и опубликовать библиотеку в новый репозиторий